# add autocomplete to select dropdown in html form

Tags: html, forms

I have a passenger form in my react application having the fileds like title, name, address etc. I have to enable autocomplete feature on this form so that it can auto populate the details saved in chrome autofill settings.

Currently, i am using `autocomplete='honorific-prefix'` for a title select  `<select autocomplete={'honorific-prefix'}>` which contains the options like Mr, Ms, Dr etc.

It's working fine for other fields like address(`<input type='text 'autocomplete="shipping address-line1">`), house number, firstname etc. but not for select.

Can you please suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist you can use either this or pure js...

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete` is meant to be used in text fields. With `select`, there's nothing to complete, as all the options are there already. When the user starts typing, the automatic `select` behavior will be to jump to words starting with the letter typed. You can always pre-select an option, or just turn the field into a text field and validate the input.